# Add Type Application | Mod Re-write not working

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, hosting

I have a site at

http://mgteurope.com

which I am transferring to a new hosting company, I set up the normal way using add-on domain, copied the database over and altered the config file to fit and then changed the name servers.

Problem, the site did not want to work as it should, I changed the name-servers back and using another domain name as to find a solution for now as seen in the URL below.

http://aylesburyfoodwall.co.uk/

The problem, .php extensions do not appear at mgteurope  e.g. I can access mgteurope.com/admin and it goes to admin page on aylesburyfoodwall.com it must be /admin.php

I checked the .htaccess file and it uses

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm .html
AddHandler x-httpd-php5  .htm .html

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

I added a RewriteEngine On at the start of the .htaccess file and no luck

I have also compared phpinfo on both and there seems to be no major difference.

My second problem of the site on aylesburyfoodwall is that it does replicate the same actions on mgteurope. When you click on the links down the left side it should veiw those items only when logged in but it does not (it loads the page though as seen in the url at the top address bar) when not logged in, it should produce a 403 forbidden error.

I assumed it would be a straight forward transfer one from hosting to another.

New hosting is shared/reseller and not dedicated.

Advice welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php
AddHandler x-httpd-php5  .php
```

I guess handlers should look like that....

And please paste the .htaccess file with mod_rewrite config.

Look at the server and php configuration, something's gotta be wrong if unauthorized users can view private pages. And bear in mind that you've got a serious security leak if this happened, so take a look at the way you authenticate/authorize users.